# SSIS 2010 update table with decimal data type gives error "type not supported.DBTYPE_DECIMAL"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update

Strange error, Using SSIS 2010 on 2012 Enterprise Edition db.
Using OLEDB connection.

Variable a,b,c are defined as Decimal in ssis.
         d     is defined as a String.

Sql Task:

```
Select min(col1),max(col1) from table_a
           where key_value = ?

where: parameter 0 is d , data type=Varchar
         resultset 1 is a , 2 is b
```

Expression task:

```
 @[User:c] = (DT_DECIMAL,2) (@[User:a] + @[User:b])
```

Sql Task:

```
Update table_a
set col2 = ?
where key_value = ?

where: parameter 0 is c (DataType=DECIMAL) and 1 is d (DataType=Varchar)
```

> Error: ... failed with the following error: "The type is not 
>            supported.DBTYPE_DECIMAL". Possible failure reasons: Problems with 
>            the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not 
>            set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

table_a is defined as

```
  d  varchar(4),
    col1 numeric(10,2),
    col2 numeric(10,2)
```

There are multiple rows of d and no index on table...
 I've tried casting and converting the value in the update statement
 Any ideas what's in error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter mapping section of your SQL task(s) to ensure the parameters are set properly.
I've seen this before, 'parameter not set correctly' is the key.